# Frequent crashes after update to Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, upgrade, crash

I have updated from Fedora 38 to 39 yesterday. Since then, I am having frequent crashes where the screen goes black for a couple of seconds, then goes back to the login page, and after I enter the password all applications are closed. No mention of the crash appears in the notifications.

This occurs randomly, after maybe 5 minutes of use, not in connection to anything specific that I am doing.

I tried booting both the current kernel 6.5.11-300.fc39.x86_64 and on the previous kernel, namely 6.5.10-200.fc38.x86_64, but both have this problem.
I don't think that this is related to a hardware issue because Windows, in dual boot, runs ok, and the freezes only appeared after the Fedora 39 update. The computer is a Dell laptop. The graphics card is the integrated Intel one.

What can I do to find the cause?

Comment: Running Gnome? Could you try something else? E.g. XFCE?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem couple of days ago.
my solution was to boot from a live usb and change my kernel version to `6.5.6.200.fc38.x86_64` on grub items to boot and it booted easily.

i used `grub-customizer` to change the settings.